# Sending signal between two child thread in MFC

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

How can i Send signal from one worker thread to another worker thread? First thread will be waiting for the signal from second thread after getting signal first thread will execute his jobs.. how can i implement this?

Comment: `PostThreadMessage()` is one way.

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject`, `SetEvent`

Comment: @JoeWillcoxson: [Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090930-00/?p=16553) Besides, chances are that you will want to synchronize in the opposite direction as well, so you're looking for the equivalent of `SendThreadMessage` ([which doesn't exist](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20081223-00/?p=19743)).

Answer (score 0):

By "send a signal" I guess you don't mean send a (Windows) message. Too complicated implementation for something really simple. Your (2nd) worker thread should create a message-loop and check for a (custom) message? Quite an overkill. Although worker threads can of course create message-loops, this is very uncommon.

Better use synchronization, and the proper object type for this is an "Event" (a simple object that can be in either signaled or non-signaled state). The 2nd thread should wait on this, and the 1st one must set it to the signaled state to notify the 2nd to do its job (this amounts to "sending the signal").

Comment: *"Although worker threads can of course create message-loops, this is very uncommon."* - No, not really. This **is** very common. Every worker thread hosting a COM object, that's compatible with the STA only, will run a message loop. In fact, any (worker) thread, that's been initialized into the STA will have to have a message loop. Synchronization through message passing is as such very, very common.